# Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions like using Blender for graphical design?

Comment: Related: [Where to ask questions about Catia (CAD software)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226163/335251) (closed as a duplicate of this question), and also [Asking specific CAD questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352882/335251) (about FreeCAD)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see a site for AutoCAD.

For Blender, you can use this site: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is now an engineering stack exchange where autocad and other cad software questions are on topic: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdamDavis, are you sure? because I don't see that software questions are listed as on topic in [tour](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Graviton Autocad questions seem to be accepted and upvoted - http://engineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=autocad

Answer (score 12):

AutoCAD questions in general are on-topic for [Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).  This also goes for other similar programs (ProE, Solid Works, Microstation, etc.)

Answer (score 10):

There are 26 questions labeled cad on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cad).

There are 142 questions labeled [cad](/questions/tagged/cad) on Stack Overflow, and 297 labeled [autocad](/questions/tagged/autocad).

Looks like Stack Overflow has the better chance of getting you an answer. I don't know if that's 'appropriate' *de jure*, but *de facto* it would seem like your best bet.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with boulder_ruby, A Stack Exchange for CAD would be a big plus. Many online sites already exist for CAD. However, the Stack Exchange mechanism seems to generally work better. I am not working with CAD of late. However, back when I was doing AutoCAD, a Stack Exchange site would have been very useful. Same holds for SketchUp.

Answer (score 7):

CAD deserves its own page on Stack Exchange and it's your responsibility as a user to see it through.

[The latest CAD Area 51 project is here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93545/computer-aided-design-cad?referrer=Gl-k7N-3v_ODwZbVfGZivA2) but at 22 users as of January 27 2016, it is fizzling. Please join.

There is a reddit post on /r/cad (which is apparently a pretty active subreddit and may serve as a temporary alternative to a separate SE page) asking people to join the above petition. [Upvote this CAD subreddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cad/comments/430r31/please_sign_this_petition_to_create_a_separate/?ref=share&ref_source=link) to further support the effort here.

gis.stackexchange.com exists, cad.stackexchange.com deserves to exist too.

Comment: Looks like the proposal failed and site has been deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no SE site specific for Autocad, but you can support the [CAD website](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad) proposal in Area 51.

Comment: Looks like the proposal failed and site has been deleted.