# Where to ask questions about Catia (CAD software)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

Where can I ask questions about [Catia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CATIA) ?

(for those who do not know, 
Catia is a very powerful 3D CAD/CAM/CAE drawing software)

Comment: What kind of questions do you want to ask?  Do you have a typical question in mind?

Comment: Basic questions like [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28496/catia-how-to-zoom-using-only-the-mouse) and [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28497/how-can-i-learn-catia), and then more advanced stuff as well (ie. how to remove a first solid from a second solid)

Comment: I don't know the Graphics Design.SE community at all, but on most SE sites, questions of that nature will be downvoted and/or closed.  the 2nd one looking for a tutorial especially.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply @psubsee2003. where can I find answers to those questions? the tutorial one in particular.

Comment: For the most part, there are no Stack Exchange sites that accept questions that just ask for recommendations or tools.  There are some that permit them (SoftwareRecommendations.SE being the most obvious one), but they have very specific guidelines on the questions.  I don't know of any SE site that will accept a question that only says "Where can I find a tutorial for X".  So to your answer, I can probably say there isn't an SE site where the tutorial request would be on-topic.  You'd have to find a forum for Catia users to ask them, or try Google.

Comment: Related: [Asking specific CAD questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352882/335251) (about FreeCAD)

Answer (score 2):

there is a CAD proposal at area51.stackexchange.com if it reaches beta you can ask such questions there.

Answer (score 2):

For the two questions you gave examples for, honestly, the best place to ask is on Google. For your [first question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28496/catia-how-to-zoom-using-only-the-mouse):

> How can I zoom in/out using just the mouse in Catia V5 ?

A search for ["catia mouse zoom"](https://www.google.com/search?q=catia%20mouse%20zoom) yields a number of results including [this tutorial video on rotate/pan/zoom with the mouse in CATIA V5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CI44TfswWFg), which appears to contain all the information you need and more.

For your [second question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28497/how-can-i-learn-catia):

> What is a good training guide to learn Catia V5 ?

A search for ["learn catia v5"](https://www.google.com/search?q=learn%20catia%20v5) yields more than a few nice looking results, some paid, some free. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to look through those results and find information that works for you.

Other sources of information that seem to have a good user base willing to answer these types of questions are: [3D CAD Forums -> CATIA](http://www.3dcadforums.com/catia-forum/) or [Eng-Tips Forums -> CATIA Products](http://www.eng-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=560).

Other dedicated CATIA forums can be found via a search for ["catia forums"](https://www.google.com/search?q=catia%20forums).

For more serious issues, and presuming your copy of CATIA is legitimate, Dassault offers [phone and email customer service](http://www.3ds.com/support/need-help/contact-support/).

This is not meant to be snarky, just a legitimate source of information. The internet has a wealth of information and, granted it sometimes has a low signal-to-noise ratio, usually information is easy to find; questions like the one you are asking may be met with resistance on SE sites because in general, SE is not a replacement for Google.

It is worth noting that I was able to find all of this quickly despite not being a graphic designer, not being particularly proficient with CAD, and never hearing of CATIA. So have no fear, the information is out there and is easy to find.

In general, it hurts the internet's SNR to ask easily searchable questions on SE sites -- the answers tend to consist of links back to the Google search result, and the search result will frequently have that answer at the top (due to SE having some weight in search results). The only thing accomplished there, then, is that one less slot is available on the front page of Google results.

So, research first, then ask! I like to refer people to this article about **[asking questions on the internet](http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-the-Internet-and-Get-It-Answered)** - it has some good general dos and don'ts that apply to all questions, not just technical. **You may wish to read it** (and pay special attention to step 1!).

Comment: In other words, just because SE exists and is awesome, doesn't mean that all questions must be asked on SE. Trying to find a place for questions like these to fit is an XY problem of sorts sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the question type.

- **Type 1:** Highly engineering-related questions about the use of the
  modeling tools, production suitable drawings, physical material
  properties, etc. The appropriate place would be [**Mechanical Engineering SE**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60942/mechanical-engineering) or even [**CAD SE**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61464/cad), which are unfortunately just proposals at [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) at the moment.
- **Type 2:** Questions about lightning, texturing, post processing and also modelling may be appropriate on [Graphic Design SE beta](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d).

Comment: Do keep in mind that this **entirely** depends on the actual question. A good question might well still be off-topic on the mentioned sites. So care must be taken to read through the site's information to determine if it's actually on-topic.

Comment: @Bart For my opinion the majority of Catia related questions should be on-topic on Mechanical Engineering SE in the future. But I agree that it is difficult regarding Graphic Design SE.

Comment: The problem though is that without a specific question we can't be sure. Catia questions could well have a Mechanical Engineering context, but I know several 3D artists who use it in other ways and in entirely separate domains.

Comment: Also questions like "how do I export a PDF from Catia" (for example) are honestly more appropriate for Google than *any* of the SE sites. In general, it hurts the internet's SNR to ask easily searchable questions on SE sites -- the answers tend to consist of links back to the Google search result, and the search result will frequently have that answer at the top (due to SE having some weight in search results). The only thing accomplished there is that one less slot is available on the front page of Google results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ask on [the Graphics Design SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d) site.