# Which Stack Exchange site is for asking about AutoCAD?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask question about [AutoCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD). For this, on which Stack Exchange site should I ask?

Comment: Related: [Where to ask questions about Catia (CAD software)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226163/where-to-ask-questions-about-catia-cad-software), [Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188052/which-stackexchange-site-is-best-for-autocad-questions)

Comment: None that I know of. But: *WANT*. Propose on http://area51.stackexchange.com/? There was a [CAD Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61464/cad) once but it was closed to lack of interest (or perhaps poor definition, looking at the comments). With some work it could probably be polished off and restarted.