# Asking specific CAD questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am an engineering student and from time to time, I find myself in the need to use Computer-Assisted-Design tools.
For my part, I mostly use FreeCAD but I don't know on which part of StackExchange such questions should be asked.

- Stack Overflow is for programming
- Super User is for General Computer Stuff
- Blender is for Computer Graphics

I don't know on which part of the sites one should turn into if the need to ask general CAD questions arise.

Comment: Can you be more specific what the question you’re intending to ask is about? [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) has a [freecad tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/freecad/info), and [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has [one as well](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/freecad/info).

Comment: A freecad search returns close to 500 questions: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=freecad&page=1 most about scripting / integrating with freecad. If you have one extra subject what your question is about you might be able to reduce that list to a manageable size.

Comment: Perhaps Engineering can help, not sure how many active people they have on those tags.

Comment: Searching for [questions only, by tag](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfreecad%5D+is%3Aquestion) returns a single site (SO); but that doesn't mean that another sites isn't a better fit, depending upon your question.

Comment: @Rob This tag search doesn’t seem to work. 3D Printing also has a tag of the same name. I previewed a custom filter to find that.

Comment: @user289905 it would seem that is [true, the main search engine misses 3DPrinting.SE](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfreecad%5D+is%3Aquestion), but the same search locally is successful. That's a bug.

Comment: @user289905 - Odd, the [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) claims the same number (68) of results as the [main search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347317/282094), yet finds the additional results of 3DP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: Related: [Which Stack Exchange site is best for AutoCAD questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188052/335251), [Where to ask questions about Catia (CAD software)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226163/335251)

Answer (score 4):

This would sort under mechanical engineering, but there is no dedicated site for that. The closest one seems to be https://engineering.stackexchange.com/ which has both CAD and mechanical-engineering tags, as well as specific ones such as Autocad and Solid Works etc.